# How to retrieve AngularList if firebase rules is set to auth !=null

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My issue is that I do not know can I retrieve data from firabase using AngularFireList. If I set database rules as with data can be used only by authorized user:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read":  "auth !=null",  // 2021-1-28
    ".write": "auth !=null",  // 2021-1-28
  }
}
```

Of course my previous fetch logic dose not work, but I do not know how to tell firebase, that user is authorized.
This is my service function:

```
constructor(
  private db: AngularFireDatabase,
  private authService: AuthService,
  public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
  }

  getItems(){
    this.pacRef = this.db.list('pacients');
    this.pacientsData = this.pacRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes=> changes.map(a=>({
        key : a.payload.key, ...a.payload.val() 
        }))));  
    return this.pacientsData;
  }
```

And here I component where I am trying get data from firabase using gatItems(key) function.

```
  constructor(private router:Router, 
    private pacientService: PacientServiceService,
    private authService: AuthService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  this.userSub = this.authService.user.subscribe(user=>{
    this.isAuthenticated = !!user;
    this.userToken = user.token;
    console.log(this.isAuthenticated);
    if (this.isAuthenticated) {
      this.pacientService.getItems().subscribe(pacientsData=>{
        this.pacientsData = pacientsData;      
      });
    }
  });
  }
```

Picture from console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkcUq.png)
Picture from authorization [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hc0W.png)

Authorization works and I am getting back token. Any help can help :) This only second month when I building something with Angular.

Comment: Why are you passing the token to the database yourself? Firebase should already be doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Given your security rules, you should only call `getItems` once the user is authenticated.

So:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userSub = this.authService.user.subscribe(user=>{
      this.isAuthenticated = !!user;
      this.userToken = user.token;
      console.log(this.isAuthenticated);
      if (this.isAuthenticated) {
        this.pacientService.getItems(this.userToken).subscribe(pacientsData=>{
          this.pacientsData = pacientsData;      
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I also think you don't need to pass the auth key yourself, as the Firebase SDKs handle that behind the scenes.

Comment: This is the problem @FrankvanPuffelen, I do not know how to send to firabase database auth key. That way I use `this.userToken` to somehow send the key, but looks like firabase dose not accept this with `list`, as I tried `this.pacRef = this.db.list('pacients?auth='+ key)`. I have seen that it works with HttpClient, but I have another structure here.

Comment: The Firebase SDKs work together behind the scenes, so that your Firebase Auth token is automatically sent with calls to the database. You don't need to do anything for that, as long as you use the SDKs. But you need to make sure the user is authenticated, which is what the code in my answer changes about what you're doing. Did you try it already?

Comment: I tried `this.pacientService.getItems().subscribe(pacientsData=>{
        this.pacientsData = pacientsData;`

Comment: But still not getting data @FrankvanPuffelen. Console error is `Error: permission_denied at /pacients: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.` but I can see that I am authenticated `{kind: "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse", localId: "CiorpuxQ1UdV9zFjTt3pBpQsY6d2", email: "minijs@inbox.lv", displayName: "", idToken: "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVmOTcxMmEwODczMTcyMG…DZiMTP2hSZsVTyM_DLRltR24tvjvqVaq9xCq2XSGzs_Co-iRw", …}`

Comment: "I tried this" -> I'm missing a lot of context there. It's best to provide the update in your question, so that you can show that you did what the code in my answer shows: move it into the auth state subscriber.

Comment: I updated question and add some screens @FrankvanPuffelen Hope it helps better tu understand my issue. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen. Our code with your improvements started to work when I changed security rules to `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth === auth.provider",  // 2021-1-28
    ".write": "auth !=null",  // 2021-1-28
  }
}` Just wanted to ask from your opinion such read security rules are ok, and I can leave them?

Comment: hello @GatisVagulis are you still having problems? There is a section on the zone where you write rules called ¨Rules playground¨ where you can check if works as you wish I want to suggest you watch the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dx_gkSb-Ch0 in there you will be able to see how to make create a make test of your differents rules and you will be able to undesterstand in a better way this topic.

Comment: Hi, @gisshizuku45 Thank you for help. I resolved this issue. Now I am working on App with Cloud Firestore. I will check out your link. Thanks